# Paperclip undefined method `title_file_name' error in Rails 4.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I installed it by following the manual on paperclip github page and I get the given error. What am I doing wrong?

I have 4 input fields: title (`text_field`), description (`text_area`), price (`text_field`) and image (`file_field`). Why am I even getting this error with the prefix `title` in it? What has the `title` field got to do with it, are there any conflicts maybe? I did create and run the migrations so this is realy kind of weird I think.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

The migration is as follows:

```
class AddImageColumnsToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_attachment :products, :image
  end
end
```

It results like so:

```
image_file_name varchar(255)
image_content_type varchar(255) 
image_file_size int(11)
image_updated_at datetime
```

[image]

**Model:**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file   :image, :styles => { :medium => "600x600>", :thumb => "258x258>" }, 
                        :default_url => "images/:style/:slug.png"
    validates :title, :content, :image, :attachment_presence => true
    validates_with AttachmentPresenceValidator, :attributes => :image
end
```

**Controller:**

```
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.image = params[:product][:image]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you show your params & table columns for your table containing the images?

Comment: Can you also paste the exact error please.

Comment: Thanks for the error. Can you also please post the Model code. I wonder if you have used the PaperClip correctly in your Model

Comment: Also, post your controller code. Did you do a plain @product = Product.new(params[:product]) or something fancy? Please put a comment here if yo uhave updated the question. That's the only way I get notified when you have modified.

Comment: @SatyaKalluri updated it :)

Comment: What's product_params?

Comment: I believe it's the rails 4 way of passing model params. I generated it with a scaffold.

Comment: Dude, checkout my answer with corrections to some of the model-validations. I hope, it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your validation. The line which says

```
validates :title, :content, :image, :attachment_presence => true
```

assumes title, content & image as 3 image-based attributes. But, I understand that only 'image' is the image-based field. So, your code should rather be:

```
validates :title, :content, :presence=>true
validates :image, :attachment_presence => true
```

Also, I don't see the 'content' field in the request-log. I guess, you mean 'description'. Make sure you have the same attribute-names in the model-validations, database-schema & view files.